# HTML-table with horizontal and vertical scrollbars on demand

Tags: html, css, html-table, scrollbars

I want a HTML-table to show the scrollbars (both horizontal and vertical), as soon as the browser window becomes too small to fully show the table.

Please see the following example: [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/0ksb8s8x/)

I suspect the main-div to be the faulty one:

```
    .myMain {
        background-color: #e9edf1;
        overflow: auto;
        width: 100%;
        top: 130px;
        left: 20px;
        bottom: 1px;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

The problem with the example code is the following: the horizontal scrollbar appears, if the window becomes too small, but it appears only after a few pixels of the tables are already cut/ invisible when resizing the browser window with the mouse. And it is shown at the bottom of the page, but I want it to be shown directly at the bottom of the table.
And the vertical scrollbar doesn't appear at all. I don't want to change the page layout visible for the user, so that's not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution which is not perfect but it works:

I used Joe Corby's Fiddle and changed only the following part in the CSS:

```
        .myMain {
        background-color: #e9edf1;
        overflow: auto;
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 120px;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
```

The scrollbars are shown at the bottom and at the right-hand-side of the browser-window (not of the table) but at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple things that threw it off for me, mainly the absolute positioning and left that was pushing the div across. Because you set it as absolute it will ignore other elements and react in it's own desired way.

Also disabling scroll via overflow:hidden on html/body will cut off part of the div coupled with it being absolutely positioned.

I've made a few changes, see below. But check the link and let me know if the desired behavior has been achieved now.

https://jsfiddle.net/0ksb8s8x/1/

```
html, body {
        font-family: Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial;
        font-size: 11px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #e9edf1;
        overflow:auto;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }

.myMain {
          background-color: #e9edf1;
          overflow: auto;
          width: 105%;
          padding: 20px;
          top: 0px;
          left: 0px;
          bottom: 1px;
          position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but not really what I expected. The problem now is, that a horizontal scrollbar for the whole page is visible always, as the header seems to have a fixed width!?!? What I wanted is that only the table has scrollbars, not the whole page.

Comment: That's perfect in the horizontal way, but a vertical scrollbar is never shown. How to achieve that too? But the height of the table should NOT be fixed (e.g. height: 100px)